# Is $\sin(\alpha)=\frac{\tan(\alpha)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\alpha)}}$ a true statment?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, fake-proofs

I'm being asked to prove the following equality

$$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{\tan(\alpha)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\alpha)}}$$

and I support the idea that they are **not** equal (the rest of my class seems to desagree with me which made me doubt a little).

The "proof" is simple:
$$\frac{\tan(\alpha)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\alpha)}}=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2(\alpha)+\sin^2(\alpha)}{\cos^2(\alpha)}}}\\=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)}\cdot |\cos(\alpha)|=\sin(\alpha)\cdot\frac{|\cos(\alpha)|}{\cos(\alpha)}=\sin(\alpha)$$
Now, this doesn´t make sense to me since $\exists\alpha$ s.t. $\cos(\alpha)>0$ and also $\exists\alpha$ s.t. $\cos(\alpha)<0$.

Does the equality hold?

---

Not much context is given when it comes to frasing the problem, the first question of our first physics homework.

I'm aware that this is very simple but my classmates seem to disagree with me on the fact that the equality is just false, maybe they know something I don´t. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right. Just find such value, and show that it's not true.

Comment: When $\alpha=\pi/2$, the RHS is not even defined.

Comment: In addition to whatever else anyone else said: note that left-hand side is periodic with period $2\pi$ (and no smaller period); the right-hand side is periodic with period $\pi$ because $\tan$ is periodic with period $\pi$. Thus they cannot be equal.

Comment: Somebody stated that, when discussing trig, you only take in to account $\alpha\in (-\pi /2, \pi/2)$. This wasn´t at all mentioned anywere on the homework, is this a valid argument, is it common practice to conside only such $\alpha$?

Comment: Not really? After all, if you're using the trigonometry to do calculations relating to an actual triangle, then you probably care more about angles between 0 and $\pi$. If the worksheet doesn't specify the domain then I'd tend to assume it's all real numbers unless told otherwise.

Comment: It's true when $\cos(\alpha)\gt0$ (which you seem to allude to).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the domain is $-\pi/2 < \alpha < \pi/2$, then the two functions are identical. However, if the domain contains any values for which $\cos(\alpha) < 0$, then as you've shown the functions differ by a factor of $-1$.

You can see it on [this graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20of%20sin%28x%29%3B%20tan%28x%29%2Fsqrt%281%2Btan%5E2%28x%29%29) - the functions track together, then the second one suddenly flips, then flips back, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

For angles $0 < \alpha < \pi/2 $ here is a geometric proof. The pictured right-angled triangle exists. Now what is the sine of $\alpha$ in that picture?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check your statement

$$\sin(\alpha) = \frac{\tan(\alpha)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\alpha)}}$$

let this equality describe a triangle $(a,b,c)$ and $0<\alpha<\pi/2$

$\sin(\alpha) = b/a$

$\cos(\alpha) = c/a$

$\tan(\alpha) = b/c$

This can be used to prove any trig identity as long as you don't forget the fact that $a^2 = b^2+c^2$.

Answer (score -2):

First,$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)}$$
Pythagorean identity: $1+\tan^2(\alpha)=\sec^2(\alpha)$
$$ \therefore \sqrt{1+\tan^2(\alpha)}=\sec(\alpha)$$
Putting it all together,
$$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)}\times\frac{1}{\sec(\alpha)}$$
But, $\sec(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\cos(\alpha)}$

$$\therefore \sin(\alpha)=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)}\times \cos(\alpha)=\sin(\alpha) $$
The statement is true.

Comment: In general $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|.$

Comment: How could you get a negative as an output on a square root function? The function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ has only a positive output so $f(\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\alpha)})$ has to be positive $\forall \alpha$ but $\sec(\alpha)$ is sometime positive and sometime negative, so they can´t be the same.

Comment: @Zac I agree. The second line should read $+/- sec(\alpha)$ obviously giving a different result.